# Why has innerHTML not been added to the w3c specs?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, w3c, innerhtml

Is there any particular reason that it isn't in any of the the specs?

It seems to be supported in all browsers, (although I'll admit it doesn't work right in all of them...since you have to use libraries like [innerXHTML](http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/innerxhtml.htm) to get it to work right thanks to Internet Explorer.

Is innerHTML in danger of disappearing from forthcoming versions of browsers?  If not shouldn't they just add it already?

I'm marking this community wiki as I know I'm gonna take a beating on my rep for this...but I just wondered why...

Comment: i thought IE pioneered innerHTML, I'm surprised that it's broken there.

Comment: What do you mean by "get it to work right thanks to Internet Explorer"?

Comment: @crescentfresh Here is what I mean: I implemented sort of a search and replace mechanism after reading an article about Javascript MVC on ALA (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/javascript-mvc/).

I implemented it the same way as Snook did except I had it pull in hidden template elements from outside.  In this way I only had to implement 2 view functions, one for tables and one for everything else.  This worked on all browsers until I added radio buttons some of which turned into textboxes when I tried it in IE8 (IE7 actually worked.) The reason for this is that the innerHTML property...

Comment: (continued from above)...of IE8 removes the double quotes from all of the attributes in the innerHTML of each of the elements.  So now I have to include a 5K library just to take care of a problem that the IE8 team should have taken care of, or even possibly created when they built IE8; 

The fact that it works on IE7 and not IE8 is just ridiculous.   And so is the fact that it works on ever single other browser than IE.  

If M$ wants to make me happy they should drop IE and just make any other browser the default cause most of the users won't even know the difference.

Comment: *sigh* I should go to sleep...

Comment: `innerHTML` contains a serialisation of the DOM to HTML, where quotes around attributes are optional in many cases. Not including them shouldn't be considered a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'll admit it doesn't work right in all of them...since you have to use libraries like innerXHTML to get it to work right thanks to Internet Explorer.

IE *invented* innerHTML; you can't really expect it to work any better than it does there.

> Is there any particular reason that it isn't in any of the the specs?

It's proposed for HTML5, for what it's worth. There is certainly no danger of it disappearing in the future, though you should continue to use it only for the simple cases where you are writing straight ‘block’ or ‘inline’ element content. Special cases like tables and selects are going to continue to be troublesome.

Comment: is the IE invented innerHTML comment meant to be sarcastic? They certainly invented it, but they failed to implement it on many elements, and it has issues on some of the elements it was implemented on.  Since none of these have been fixed in IE7 or IE8 (except the exception in IE8 for tables) I certainly DO expect it to work better than it does in IE... I'd like it to work like it does in all other browsers... on all elements.

Comment: @scunliffe Agreed.  We're not using the same type of wheel on our cars today that the first caveman that invented it did.

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#innerhtml

There's absolutely no way it's in danger, thousands of applications rely on it and doing so would be a horrible idea.

Comment: Sweet.  I guess I can use it then.

Answer (score 0):

IE, being the inventor of dynamically modifying the content has gone with it all the way - other browsers didn't!

Passing the string as innerHTML means that the string will get through a normalization process before it gets passed to the element. Meaning it will get transformed fom a string into a proper html parsing content.

Firefox implemented it wrongly. It doesn't distinguish between html:innerHTML and html:innerText and plain string:text. The difference is literally obvious for IE, but not for FF. Hence the difference in handling situations and the confusion of FF only coders when they go back to the master.